# Support bigrams in Topic Modeling using Mallet Java Api

Tags: java, lda, n-gram, mallet

We would like to build a topic model with bigrams.
What is the recommended way to implement this in Java?

Currently, we use Mallet Java API. 
Specifically, ParallelTopicModel while passing tokens as a string to data parameter of Instance object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most reliable way to account for n-grams is to modify the input. For example, you might replace `new york` with `new_york`, and then tokenize using a pattern that accepts `_` as a letter character. Mallet allows you to specify a file with strings to treat as single tokens when you import documents:

```
bin/mallet import-file --help
A tool for creating instance lists of feature vectors from comma-separated-values
...
--replacement-files FILE [FILE ...]
  files containing string replacements, one per line:
    'A B [tab] C' replaces A B with C,
    'A B' replaces A B with A_B
  Default is (null)
```

This mode of use requires you to identify specific n-grams. You could also modify the input file to include all bigrams, so `to be or not to be` would become `to_be be_or or_not not_to to_be`. I don't know whether that would produce anything useful.

There are also topic model variants that "natively" support n-gram identification, but at a significant cost in training time and model quality. I would not recommend using any of them.